# Is DISTINCT always implied in a subquery used in an IN clause?

Tags: sql-server

```
select * from tab4 where a  in (select b from tab4)
select * from tab4 where a  in (select DISTINCT b from tab4)
```

The above 2 queries produce the exact same query plan and IO stats, so it seems like the DISTINCT in the 2nd query does not make any impact and is ignored by SQL Server. (I have a "Hash Map(Partial aggregate" operator in both the queries, which I'm guessing is used for DISTINCT)

Is this true for all cases, or am I just hitting an edge case?

Comment: Related on DBA http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51430/is-using-distinct-as-a-hint-in-subqueries-useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DISTINCT` does not make any logical difference here. It is therefore meaningless to say that it is implied or not.

On an implementation level SQL Server knows this. Using `DISTINCT` in a subquery to improve performance is superstitious. It does nothing.

In fact it is not clear to me why it would even help in all cases. Distincting a set can be costly. And SQL Server will not do it if it is not a good idea.

Comment: Right..  I was trying to evaluate if the penalty of distinct would be less or more than the penalty of having a larger number of elements in the IN clause. I realise that logically its the same but sometimes implementation details might matter

Comment: @Akash your question is absolutely valid. It does not make a difference. Don't do it. If you're curious about such matters search for "sql server query optimization" or "sql server execution plan". You'll be able to answer such questions yourself.